# Drupal7 managed_file form

Tags: forms, drupal-7

I have this managed_file form in a Drupal customized module,  with this form a user can upload an image and saved it under sites/default/files.

```
     $form['Background_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#progress_message' => t('Please wait...'),
     '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
    '#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
     ///'#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/'
    '#default_value' => $this->options['Background image'],
    );
```

how to add a function to get the uploaded file?
I tried this but it didnt work.

```
    $image = file_load($form_state['values']['Background_image']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just create the form element, and then use the `$form_state['values']` array to get the fid. like this:

```
function my_module_form() {
  $form = array();
  $form['background_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#progress_message' => t('Please wait...'),
    '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
    '#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/',
    '#default_value' => $this->options['background image'] //fid
   );
   return $form;
}

function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['background_image']);
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  file_usage_add($file, 'module_name', 'entity_name', $entity_id);
  file_save($file);
}
```

I just wrote that on the fly so I'm sure there are syntax errors :) but that's the idea. If you are not getting the file id from `$form_state['values']['background_image']`, I would try dying in your submit handler and dumping the contents of `$form_state['values']`:

```
function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  die(var_dump($form_state['values']['background_image']));
}
```

That should tell you a few things about whats being returned from your form.